# Listing customers using the go stripe api client

Tags: go, stripe-payments

I am trying to list all my customers in stripe and I am getting this error:

> 2018/08/14 19:14:21 Requesting GET api.stripe.com/v1/customers
> 2018/08/14 19:14:21 http: proxy error: dial tcp [::1]:3001:
>
> getsockopt: connection refused

The code snippet I am using is:

```
stripe.Key = "sk_test_abc123"

params := &stripe.CustomerListParams{}
params.Filters.AddFilter("limit", "", "3")
i := customer.List(params)
for i.Next() {
    c := i.Customer()
    fmt.Printf("customer is..\n %v", c)
}
```

I removed my stripe private test key ofcourse in the above snippet.

Why would I be getting this type of error?  Is it my laptops firewall or something?

**Update**

It seems the issue is because I am using https://github.com/codegangsta/gin for live reloading.
Is there a way to get this to work?

I just ran my go project by doing:

```
go build
./proj-name
```

And the API called worked fine.

Comment: Your proxy isn't listening on `[::1]:3001`, or firewalled, or otherwise unreachable.

Comment: @Peter The api is for stripe, so not sure what proxy you are referring to.

Comment: @Blankman this proxy: "http: proxy error: dial tcp [::1]:3001:"

Comment: @AdamSmith That doesn't look like a stripe api call to me, it should be like api.stripe.com/v1/customers that is why I am confused.

Comment: @Blankman no, it's clearly not, that's why no one has responded saying how your code is wrong. Something seems borked about your network config.

Comment: @AdamSmith looks like it is because I am using https://github.com/codegangsta/gin for live reloading.